# How to evaluate this integral $I= \int_a^t {(t-s)^{\alpha-2}f (s)\, ds} $ with $0 <\alpha <1$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a positive real valued function say $f$. Suppose this function is also differentiable. Then is the following integral defined for any $t>a$ and $0 <\alpha <1$?
$$I= \int_a^t {(t-s)^{\alpha-2}f (s)\, ds} $$
The problem is if i apply integration by parts by taking $dv=(t-s)^{\alpha-2}ds$, $u=f (s)$ then i could not apply the upper limit. Any idea on how to evaluate this integral would be of great help.

Comment: you asked a similar question for differentiating the integral

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is differentiable, it is also continuous, and therefore bounded on $[a,t]$, say $|f|\le M$ for some $M\gt 0$. Therefore $|\int_a^t (t-s)^{\alpha-2}f(s)ds|\le M|\int_a^t (t-s)^{\alpha-2}ds|=\dfrac{M(t-a)^{\alpha-1}}{\alpha-1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response. But i forgot to add an important part in the question. The alpha lies between 0 and 1. In that case will the integral be well defined?

Comment: Integrals of $x^{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha\in \Bbb R$ are well defined.

Comment: but here the integrand is of the form $1/(t-s)^{2-\alpha}$. Will the integrand not become $\infty$ if apply the upper limit $t$

Comment: Sorry, then the improper integral diverges